# Confusion about exact DEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

If I understand the definition of an exact de correctly, if $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0 $ and $M_y=N_x$, then 
$$f(x,y)=\int M(x,y)dx + g(y)$$
 and 
$$g'(y)=\int M(x,y)dx-N(x,y)$$

1) Is my interpretation correct?

2) Is M always the expression in the given equation preceding dx? Is N always the expression preceding Dy?

Answer (score 1):

1.
Your interpretation is partially correct. 
$$
F(x, y) := \int M(x,y)dx + g(y)
$$
However:
$$
g'(y) := N(x,y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int M(x,y)dx
$$
This is because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = N$.
$$
F(x, y) := \int M(x,y)dx + g(y)
\implies
N(x, y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int M(x,y)dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(y) \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int M(x,y)dx + g'(y)
$$

2. Yes, $M(x, y)$ precedes $dx$ and $N(x, y)$ precedes $dy$